# How do you deal with importing built-in libraries under windows using PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-2.6

I have python-2.6 installed and use pycharm-3.1.3 (community edition) to develop.

But the imports of the built-in libraries (for instance - `datetime`) are marked as errors by the given IDE.

[image]

It only happens for built-in libraries, the external ones that are located in `<pythondir>/Lib` (for instance `base64`) are imported without problems - IDE can resolve symbols from them for intellisense and whatnot.

So the question is how to deal with this?

PS: I know I can mark it as "ignore this import error" but then the library symbols won't be autocompleted.

Comment: Have you set the default python interpreter in the project's configuration? It should load all the modules into it's database after you do it.

Comment: @user3557327: yes I have. If I hadn't - it wouldn't use intellisense at all and wouldn't find other (external) libraries

Comment: @user3557327: oh, I removed the interpreter and re-added it. And now it works fine. That is weird. Could you please put "Please re-add it then" as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened right after an upgrade from 3.0 to 3.1.x, so probably it's just some upgrade issue.

The solution is to re-add interpreter. After that all built-in modules are resolved fine.